# React Native: Flat List and react-native-menu

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to have a react native menu on every list on FlatList. However, only in the last item is the menu appearing. How to achieve on each list to have a react native menu. Please see my code below and link for screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/15dHZ.png

Declaration of Menu and FlatList

```
import Menu, { MenuItem } from 'react-native-material-menu';

_menu = null;

setMenuRef = ref => {
  this._menu = ref;
};

hideMenu = () => {
  this._menu.hide();
};

showMenu = () => {
  this._menu.show();
};

<FlatList
  data={this.state.forms}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.formRow}>
      <View style={styles.formRowText}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Menu
          ref={this.setMenuRef}
          button={<Text onPress={this.showMenu}>Show menu</Text>}
        >
          <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Response</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Menu item 2</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </View>
    </View>
  )}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
/>;
```